# Read a txt file from PC using UART - Atmega32A

Tags: c, uart, spi, atmega, atmelstudio

I am a beginner in microprocessor programming. I created an array and sent datas using UART. I want to read a text file and create this array using datas in the text file with the simplest way possible. Any suggestion to proceed? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#define F_CPU 8000000UL  // Clock freq

char flag = 0;

void usart_init(void){
 UCSRA = 0x02;
 UCSRB = 0x98; // Enable transmitter Enable receiver Enable Interrupt
 UCSRC = (1<<UCSZ1) | (1<<UCSZ0); // set as 8 bit data, no parity bit and 1 stop bit. 
 UBRRH = 0x00;
 UBRRL = 109;
}

int main(void){
 usart_init();

 while(1){

  unsigned char array[5]={0x44,0xAA,0x33,0xBB,0x55};

  for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
   UDR = array[i];
   UDR = 0xFF;
   _delay_ms(100);
  }

  sei();
  if(flag == 1)
  {
   flag = 0;
   UCSRB = 0x98;
  }
 } 
}

ISR(USART_RXC_vect){

  UCSRB = (0<<RXEN)|(0<<TXEN)|(0<<RXCIE);
  flag = 1;
}
```

Comment: char const array[] = "blah blah blah" 0xa "...." 0xa "...." ....;

Comment: Best way is to copy from your text file and paste its content into the source using something like above. Beware to the modifier `const`, otherwise you waste memory. You can also split data in more lines.

Comment: Do you know the size (or the maximum size) of the file in advance? How much RAM does your processor have? Typically microprocessors never store an entire file or huge chunk of readings in memory, they process the data as it comes in (maybe storing the most recent few bytes in a circular buffer) and then discard the data.

Comment: I take it you want to read the text file _using UART_, right? Because nothing else makes sense.

Comment: @Lundin yes. I want to read the text file using UART and assign datas to an array as you can see in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are working with a microcontroller so you can't handle a file directly. You had to code every value (copy & paste) in your source code.

```
unsigned char const array[5]={0x44,0xAA,0x33,0xBB,0x55};
```

You had to do this even for a large array.

Comment: I know that but my question is how can I handle a file? Can I write a program to read text file and save datas to microcontroller's memory?

Comment: When you say memory, do you mean volatile memory (RAM) or non-volatile (such as EEPROM, FLASH or Program memory)?

Comment: I am not sure that it is possible or not but I was thinking EEPROM and FLASH. File will be max 20 bytes.